# $y=(1+\frac{1}{n^3})(1+\frac{2^3}{n^3})...(1+\frac{n^3}{n^3})$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $$y=\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^3}{n^3}\right)...\left(1+\frac{n^3}{n^3}\right)$$ then what is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } y^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ ?

Can anyone guide me for this? Hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT. compute 1/n ln(y) first

Comment: this will convert it to a sum

Comment: COUGH a riemann sum

Comment: *asthma attack* which can be represented as a definite integral

Comment: @SakethMalyala I think, if you had a stroke, you would write the whole solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Insert stroke and heart attack**

First let's let $u$ = $\ln(y)$ so that $\frac{u}{n}=\ln(y^\frac{1}{n})$.

We have $u = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{k^3}{n^3}\right)$

Therefore, $\ln(y^\frac{1}{n})=\frac{u}{n}=\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^3\right)$.

By the Limit Definition of an Integral, this is equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{u}{n}=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln(1+x^3)\,dx$.

Taking the exponential of both sides gives us

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} y^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{ \int_0^1 \ln(1+x^3)\,dx}$$

Comment: *slow clap for that first sentence alone*

Comment: Actually, this is rigorous after the edits.  Well done!  (+1)

Comment: And the result of the integral is quite nice ! $\to +1$

Answer (score 6):

In order to complete the previous answer, you may also notice that once
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{y_n}=\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x^3)\,dx \tag{1}$$
is established, by integration by parts and partial fraction decomposition it follows that:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{y_n}= \color{red}{\large 4\,e^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}-3}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Woah, how did you evaluate that integraL??

Comment: @SakethMalyala: as I told: by integration by parts the problem boils down to computing $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^3}$, that is given by a combination of a logarithm and an arctangent, by partial fraction decomposition.